# Interpretation of log odds

Tags: logistic-regression

Equation of log odds:

[image]

Example:

Log odds of getting a heart disease-->

0.8=2.5(Hypertension)+0.3(Gender)+0.06(Age)+15

**How is this equation interpreted?**

Answer (score 1):

this is an equation for a binary logistic regression. assume P is the probability of a sample belonging to class one. 1-P is then the probability of the sample NOT belonging to class one, in other words, it belongs to class two. the odds are the ratio between the two probabilities, i.e. the higher the log odds, the larger the probability of the sample belonging to class one.

say the right hand side is A. then, solving for P gives:

P = e^A / (1 + e^A) = 0.69 for A = 0.8.

So, the probability of the sample belonging to class one is about 70% here.